# When using the simplex method , how do we know that the number of basic variables will be exactly equal to n+1?

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra, simplex

A *simplex* is a polytope of n+1 extreme points in $R^n$.

In linear programming, the algorithm of the *simplex method* works by iteratively constructing simplexes.  Each iteration involves both an entering variable, which has the largest reduced cost, and an exiting variable, which is the variable which must leave in order to allow all of the constraints to be satisfied, when the entering variable enters.

Eventually we find a simplex which corresponds to the optimal solution.  Each simplex corresponds to a basic feasible solution, with each `extreme point`/`vertex` of the simplex corresponding to a *basic variable*.

(this implies that all simplexes have n+1 extreme points).  My question is - how do we know that the solution will have exactly n+1 basic variables?

**Edits**
this is the resource i have been using: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci1vBGn9yRc

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your understanding of the simplex method is correct. it iterates over the vertexs/extreme points  of a given polytope (given by the constraints). One of those extreme points is the maximum/minimum because the polytope(like all polytopes)  is convex.

A simplex does not have to have a certain number of extreme points. although it will have extreme points for all intersection of constraints that are feasible and only those, it however can be difficult to see which intersections will be feasible  .

Comment: This resource is making me think it is a bunch of simplexes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci1vBGn9yRc

Comment: @Hunle Ah, now I see, I had not heard this explanantion before. This is indeed correct. I was (slightly) wrong with terminology(I called a polytope which is not a simplex a simplex). This way of thinking about it is somewhat more complex than how I describe it. The simplex that that professor is talking about is the space spanned by a basic solution, it has n vertices by assign. It has to have them because the solution always has n constraints and each constarint corresponds with a basic variable. The space in which it exists has dimension n-1 (so it is equivalent to your statement)

Comment: @Hunle continuation: what is n is ofcourse not really important but what you should understand is that the number of basic variables is equal to the number of restrictions. so equal to the dimension of a column of the restriction matrix  A. Note that slack variables can be basic variables, therefore the simplex alwys has the desired number of points. This is neccessary because we only look at the outside of the polytope of the feasible region and so all inequaliteis must hold. Therefore for each constriant there needs to be a basic variable to balance the equation.

Comment: @Hunle I have slightly changed my answer I can include what I said in the comments as well. I do not like this interpretation though. It gives more insight in why the simplex  method works algebraically nand how to derive it. But it is much harder to see why it works intuitively.

Comment: OKay, thank you @zen.  Would you be able to give an explanation for how it works intuitively?  There is a bounty out :)

Comment: So, I understand that the the simplex is the subspace *spanned* by the basis matrix.  And I understand that number of basic variables is equal to the number of restrictions because the basis matrix is always a square `m` x `m` where m is the number of constraints.  However, I do not understand what else you are saying about “we only look at the outside of the polytope of the feasible region”?

Comment: @Hunle The whole feasible region is the polytope given by all inequalities.  However we make the inequalities equalities by adding the slack variables, In the new problem we then get that the inside of the polytope is not considered anymore. Instead we require the solution to be exactly at the hyperplanes at which the constraints hold exactly (remeber that we treat slack variables as true variables, so that this is always possible). The intersection of these hyperplanes are solutions. These hyperplanes are also the outside facets of the polytope.